# MySQL Update: Use index for left join, but ignore it for order by

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, sql-update

I use the following query:

```
update a left join b on a.type = b.type and a.name like b.pattern set a.b_id = b.id, a.flags = 1 where a.flags = 0;
```

b.type and b.name are defined as index, that means MySQL tries to match with this condition:

```
order by b.type, b.pattern
```

Is it possible to use the index only for the real matching, *not* for the order by-statement?

For reference:

More then one b-records can match one a-record, but only the b-record with the lowest id should be used.

The problem is, that MySQL does not support to set up a user defined order by-statement in updates with joins. If this feature would be supported, I could easy add to the end:

order by b.id

Is it possible to fix the issue without using
a select-Subquery (as join) to realize fieldset order in updates with more then one tables?

Comment: I really don't understand your question.  However, ORDER BY isn't supported in UPDATEs because the order is irrelevant.  All the matching records are going to get updated as atomic operation and the order this happens in doesn't matter.

Comment: I don't understand the question either. But @bobwienholt ORDER BY is supported in UPDATE, but it only makes sense when you use it with LIMIT. Apart from that you are correct.

Comment: The OP's problem is that with an update-from-join, it is possible to have more than one source value being written to the same destination row. The apparent order in which this happens affects the resulting data.

Comment: Ah... that makes sense now.  Still, it seems that relying on the order of the update operations is not such a great idea.

Comment: @bobwienholt Indeed. As discussed in my answer, the real solution is to eliminate the duplicates before applying the update operation, not to change the way the update applies.

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on *any* particular order (which is really more of a "priority") applying to the duplicate values, as the DBMS is free to use whichever comes to hand, whether or not an index is involved.

Instead, you should use a sub-query to select only the rows from `b` that you want to use. Note that this is not an `Order by`, but a `Group by`, since the DBMS could still choose to apply the rows in whatever order it liked after testing the join conditions. For the simplified case in your question, it would look like this:

```
Update a 
Left Join
( 
    Select type, pattern, min(id) as min_id 
    from b 
    group by type, pattern 
) as x
On a.type = x.type and a.name like x.pattern
Set a.b_id = x.min_id, a.flags = 1
Where a.flags=0;
```

Update: Since you've clarified that you need the whole row with the lowest ID, the sub-query becomes rather more complicated - you have to first find the lowest ID which is a match, and then get the details of that row. For readability, you could break this into two steps, using a temporary table, although a sub-query with the same content is equivalent.

```
-- Find "best" match in b for each row in a
Select a.id, min(b.id) as min_b_id
From a 
Left Join b

-- Apply as many join conditions as required here
On a.type = b.type and a.name like b.pattern

-- Only calculate for those rows you wish to update
Where a.flags = 0

Group by a.id
```

This table (or sub-query) would then need to be joined to both `a` (to find which rows to update) and `b` (to find the full details to update with).

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is, that in our productive database we set more columns in the a-table with data from the b-table, e.g. a.x=b.x, a.y=b.y ... The b.id will be not copied to the a-table and represents only a priority for matching.

Comment: I see, that will make things complicated. However, the basic concept remains: you don't want to change the order of duplicates, you want to write a query such that there are no duplicates.

Comment: It may help to populate a temporary table with the "best" id from b for each row in a, then in the update join a to temp, temp to b.

Comment: It is not a option to populate rows from the a and b in one temporary table: every secound, our system adds about 100 records. That means, that the a table is very large.

Comment: Concretely, I use this query: UPDATE
  cdrs AS a
LEFT JOIN
  rates AS b ON a.address = b.address AND a.leg = b.leg AND a.src like b.src AND a.dst like b.dst AND timeb(a.date, b.timeb) AND (a.dst like b.prefix OR a.src like b.prefix)
SET a.cid = b.cid, a.article_id = b.article_id, a.price_id = b.price_id, a.price = b.setup+b.price/60*a.billtime, a.flags = 1
WHERE a.flags IS NULL;
Do you have any hint to match with the b.id as priority? Thanks, Philipp.

Comment: The temp table is just a convenience for making the query more readable. If you're trying to make this "keep up" with a large number of insertions, perhaps you should consider a trigger. That way, you would only be dealing with one row at a time, and could simply say "for this row in `cdrs`, what is the 'best' row in `rates`". Incidentally, I would advise against using an ID to indicate priority; it would be better to have an explicit `priority` column which you could manipulate if necessary.